# How to make reCaptcha badge transparent

Tags: recaptcha, transparent

How might I make the reCaptcha badge transparent?  I don't want to hide it, I just want to make the white background transparent.  I can do it by changing the code in the inspect pane, but can't figure out how to add additional css to make it permanent.  Running Wordpress 5.8.3.

I've tried adding the info from the inspect in Additional CSS, but it doesn't work:

```
.rc-anchor-light {
    background: #f9f9f900;
    color: #000; 
}
```

Have also tried adding the .grecaptcha-badge:

```
.grecaptcha-badge .rc-anchor-light {
    background: #f9f9f900;
    color: #000;
}
```

Here's a screenshot of what I'm hoping to do:
[recaptcha transparent screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1vpL.png)

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

you can add to your css file the following:

```css
.grecaptcha-badge
{
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

The range between 0 and 1 makes it fully transparent, or 100% visible.
This configuration shows the badge with 30% opacity.

Hope this help you, cheers!